# How do I PostAsync() with multiple simple types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How do I PostAsync() with multiple simple types as parameters, I have the action controller below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}")]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials([FromUri]string username, string password)
{

   //Do Stuff......
   return Ok("Login Successful");

}
```

I am trying to invoke it from a .Net Framerwork 4.5 Client application as below:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(string username, string password)
{


     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

     var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
        { "username", "test123" }
     };

     var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
     var result = await client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}", content);
     string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     // return URI of the created resource.
     return result.Headers.Location;
}
```

I have tried mutiple ways so far and have done a lot of reading, most recently [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

I understand that it is easier to deal with complex types than it is to deal with simple types and that by default complex types are encoded into the request body/content while simple types are encoded into the URI.

I have tried to post data by sending key/value pairs encoded using `FormUrlEncodedContent(string)` by sending Json through `StringContent()`, I have tried with both single and multiple parameters but I understand the limitation is only with complex types now.

I have read many MSDN posts and tutorials, maybe I am missing a crucial piece of information.

The controller action above does get executed but with both paramerters having a 
string value of "{username}" and "{password}"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write

```
[Route("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}")]
```

You are saying "match the username and password parameters, in the specified order, from the Uri", so whatever you send through the body of the POST will be ignored.

You are explicitly passing {username} and {password} as parameters:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}", content);
```

You should be doing this instead:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "users/verifyLoginCredentials/username/test123");
var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If you want to post the data as the body instead of part of the URL, use this:

```
[Route("users/VerifyLoginCredentials")]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials(string username, string password)

 var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
    { "username", "yourUsername" },
    { "passwird", "test123" }
 };

 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
 var result = await client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials/", content);
 string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, but PostAsync() unlike GetAsync() does not have an overload for a single parameter :(

Comment: @Aboudi I forgot about that, sorry. Fixed

Comment: Awesome, is this the only way to transmit simple types?

Comment: @Aboudi When you want the parameters to go in the URL, yes. If you want it to go in the body instead, you could keep using what you were doing

Comment: Oh, I guess I could not figure how to extract the HttpContent sent to the Action using my original method, could you briefly explain how I could do that? I guess the first step is to remove the parameters from the Route so the body does not get ignored?

Comment: @Aboudi The answer by AndreiDragotoniu shows an example of that

Comment: But that is a complex type not a simple type, isn't it? Sorry to bother you with this but curiosity is killing me

Comment: I have tried this but it gives a 404 Error, I think this is because it does not know where to get the parameters from and cannot make the assumption when there is more than one, when I added at least one parameter and decorated it, it worked, but it still shows the value of the parameter is nulll. What I couldn't figure out is how to read the body data from within the scope of the Action when a request was made with `FormUrlEncodedContent()`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to create a model which contains everything you need.

An example would be:

```
public class LoginModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get;set }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get;set }
}
```

you can now do:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/verifyLoginCredentials")]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials([FromBody]LoginModel model)
{
   //validate your model    
   if ( model == null || !ModelState.IsValid )     
   {
       return BadRequest();
   }

   //stuff
   return Ok();
}
```

To use it you would do something like this:

```
var model = new LoginModel { Username = "abc", Password="abc" } ;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{               
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");               

    var result = await client.PostAsync("your url", content);
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Do not send passwords in the URI as anyone can intercept the request and see what the password is.

Any data which needs to remain secret you send it in the body of the request and make sure the request is over https as that encodes the headers and the post body so no one can look at the data.

Comment: Thanks, Will give it a shot it should work, yes I am aware that encoding the password into the URI is a security risk, that was the next thing for me to look which is why I was using POST and not GET

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost("{coverPagePath}")] 
public void Post([FromRoute] string coverPagePath, [FromBody] UserCoverpage value)
{
   var args = new[] { WebUtility.UrlDecode(coverPagePath).Replace("\\", "/") };
   userCoverpageService.Create(value, args);
}
...
//test:
var json = item.SerializeToJson(true);
HttpContent payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// act
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"/api/UserCoverpage/{coverPagePath}", payload); 
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
output.WriteLine(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just write:

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
const string url = "users/verifyLoginCredentials?username=oneuser&password=123";
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```